# Django template how to read URL view keyword

Tags: django, templates, url, view

I'm calling this url:

```
url(r'^new/(?P<gigi>\d+)/$', views.myview.as_view(), name='create'),
```

as

> 127.0.0.1:8000/new/33

this is what django debug says:

```
Funzione View   Argomenti   Parole chiave   Nome URL
my_app.views.myview()
{'gigi': u'33'}
```

I've tried to insert in the template:

```
{{request.path}}           # return full url
{{request.GET.gigi}}   # return nothing
```

the view see the gigi as 33 correctly, but can gigi be seen from inside of template?

this is the view:

```
class SimpleCreateView(CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
         mygigi=self.kwargs['gigi']
        return super(SimpleCreateManView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You need to show your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `gigi` param in your view, and then send it to the view in your `context`:

```
def myview(request, gigi):
    context = {'gigi': igigi}
    ...
```

EDIT:

After your edit:

```
class SimpleCreateView(CreateView):

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(SimpleCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx.update({'gigi': self.kwargs['gigi']})
        return ctx
```